# How to grep an exact string with slash in it?

Tags: regex, macos, command-line, grep

I'm running macOS.

There are the following strings:

**/superman**

/superman1

**/superman/batman**

/superman2/batman

**/superman/wonderwoman**

/superman3/wonderwoman

**/batman/superman**

/batman/superman1

**/wonderwoman/superman**

/wonderwoman/superman2

I want to grep only the bolded words.

I figured doing grep -wr 'superman/|/superman' would yield all of them, but it only yields /superman.

Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -E '(^|/)superman($|/)' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/BwWryu):

```
s="/superman
/superman1
/superman/batman
/superman2/batman
/superman/wonderwoman
/superman3/wonderwoman
/batman/superman
/batman/superman1
/wonderwoman/superman
/wonderwoman/superman2"
grep -E '(^|/)superman($|/)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
/superman
/superman/batman
/superman/wonderwoman
/batman/superman
/wonderwoman/superman
```

The pattern matches

- `(^|/)` - start of string or a slash
- `superman` - a word
- `($|/)` - end of string or a slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '/superman\>'
```

`\>` is the "end of word marker", and for "superman3", the end of word is *not* following "man"

---

The problems with your `-w` solution:

1. `|` is *not* special in a **basic** regex. You either need to escape it or use `grep -E`
2. read the man page about how `-w` works:

   > The  test  is  that  the
   >             matching  substring  must  either  be at the beginning of the line, or **preceded by a non-word
   >             constituent character**. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by  a
   >             non-word  constituent  character

   In the case where the line is `/batman/superman`,

   - the pattern `superman/` does not appear
   - the pattern `/superman` is:

     - at the end of the line, which is OK, but
     - is prededed by the character "n" which ***is*** a word constituent character.

`grep -w superman` will give you better results, or if you need to have superman preceded by a slash, then my original answer works.